# Rearranging an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Consider the expression $c = 3x^2+2xy+2y^2$. Show that the function $$h(x,y) = 2y(3x+y) + 2(x+2y)(-x+y-2y^2(x+2y))$$
may be written in the form $h(x,y)= g(c)$ or $h(x,y)\le g(c)$ for some $g$ to be found.

---

So I decided to expand $h(x,y)$ first:

\begin{align}
h(x,y) &= 2y(3x+y) + 2(x+2y)(-x+y-2y^2(x+2y)) \\
&= 2y(3x+y) + 2(x+2y)(-x+y)-4y^2(x+2y)^2 \\
&=6xy+2y^2-2x^2+2xy-4xy+4y^2-4x^2y^2-16xy^3-16y^4 \\
&= 4xy+6y^2-2x^2-4x^2y^2-16xy^3-16y^4
\end{align}

But I don't really know how to get this. I assume $g$ has the form $$g(c) = \alpha c^2 + \beta c$$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ however I'm not sure how to proceed. can anyone help?

Edit: Note I want to solve $g(c)=0$ for $c>0$ after so a function of the form $g(c)=\alpha c$ or $g(c) = \beta c^2$ would not work.

Comment: I have a feeling that It could be easy if the variables would be $(x,y)$ instead of $(x_1, x_2)$

Comment: @corbah I have changed this now but am still not really seeing anything. There is a quadratic in $x+2y$ however it doesn't seem to factorise nicely.. That's all I can see.

Comment: Do we have $x>0, y>0$ constraint? I have something in my mind, I'll write here when I get home.

Comment: @corbah no $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can re-write

$c = \begin{bmatrix} x,  y \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 1 \\
        1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\  y \end{bmatrix}
$

Now we have (from your expansion),

$h(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} x,  y \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 2 \\
         2 & 6 \\
        \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\  y \end{bmatrix} - 4y^2(x+2y)^2 $, we know squares are positive, then

$h(x,y) \le\begin{bmatrix} x,  y \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 2 \\
         2 & 6 \\
        \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\  y \end{bmatrix}$

$h(x,y) \le 2c + 
\begin{bmatrix} x,  y \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -8 & 0 \\
         0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\  y \end{bmatrix}$

$h(x,y) \le 2c - 8x^2 + 2y^2 \le 2c + 4x^2 + y^2$, this is the equation $(i)$

We also know that $c = (x+y)^2 + 2x^2 + y^2 \implies (ii): 4x^2 + 2y^2 \le 2c$

Therefore from $(i)$ & $(ii)$

$h(x,y) \le 2c + 4x^2 + 2y^2 \le 2c + 2c \le 4c$